# Derive Country Code From IP Address Using Java WebServices

Tags: java, web-services

I would like to parse an ip address using a web based GeoIP service. I am following [maxminds](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/) tutorials online. He recommends using 'WebServiceClient using the WebServiceClient.Builder' and suggests 'providing the Builder constructor your MaxMind userId and licenseKey'. Is this necessary? I would like to employ for example, a web-based [webservicex](http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP) browser-based solution. Can some one suggest how I can achieve this? Please do not suggest off-line resources.

```
    String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP";

    // The params here hold the id and the key, which I do not want to employ, 
    // I would prefer to access via url

    WebServiceClient.Builder builder = new WebServiceClient.Builder(1,url);
    WebServiceClient client = builder.build();

    InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName("128.101.101.101");

    CountryResponse responce = client.country(ipaddress);
    Country country = responce.getCountry();

    System.out.println("country code: " + country.getIsoCode());
    System.out.println("country name: " + country.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted is actually querying a remote service to the the location of the IP. But, since this is a paid service, you need to provide the userId and licenseKey.
If you want to use MaxMind online services, you will have to get those details. They do provide a free option, but, as you have probably realized, it's offline.

EDIT: you can also give this one a try: https://freegeoip.net/